# angular2 fullcalendar not working

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Hello i am using fullcalendar with my angular2 project.But i am not able to properly display the calendar itself.There is no error shown in the console but the calendar and events doesnt display. this is what it is displaying as of now
[image]

Here are my codes.Please let me know if i need to attach any more files

angular.cli.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "calendar"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css"
        
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/ap-angular2-fullcalendar/angular2-fullcalendar.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/moment.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CalendarComponent} from 'ap-angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CalendarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  calendarOptions:Object = {
        height: 'parent',
        fixedWeekCount : false,
        defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
          {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2016-09-01'
          },
          {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2016-09-07',
            end: '2016-09-10'
          },
          {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2016-09-16T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2016-09-11',
            end: '2016-09-13'
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-09-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2016-09-12T12:30:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2016-09-12T12:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-09-12T14:30:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2016-09-12T17:30:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Dinner',
            start: '2016-09-12T20:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2016-09-13T07:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2016-09-28'
          }
        ]
      };
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

Please help.I am stuck.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

> Update 1,Now it is not working only on restarting the machine.The console says its not finding CalendarComponent in the specified directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by removing the line,

> height:'parent'

from the component.Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, now its work for me, please refer following information

You need to include your `style.css` to

**import the fullcalendar css**

If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your `style.(scss|css)` file:

`@import "fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css";`
If this does not work you can try by importing fullcalendar.

`npm install --save fullcalendar`
and include:

`@import "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css";`